# Add category name to Smart Search results?

Tags: joomla-3.x, plugin, smartsearch

I want to add the articles category name, when the results show up for "Smart search" plugin. right now it only shows the article name. i tried to use this code, but it didn't work:

```
<?php $title = $this->escape($item->category_title); ?>
                            <?php if ($params->get('link_category') && $item->catslug) : ?>
                                <?php $url = '<a href="' . JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->catslug)) . '" itemprop="genre">' . $title . '</a>'; ?>
```

Can anyone tell me if there are any other way to do it? :)

Comment: Do you mean to show the article's category name on the search results page of the Smart Search component? Anyhow, I don't think this is supported with the current Smart Search system, but maybe I am wrong.

Comment: yes thats what i mean. i know its not supported ,but there may be a small code to write to implement it?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this supported with the current Smart Search system.
With non supported, I mean that there won't be a quick and easy way to do this.

I haven't dig deep into the Smart Search, so maybe I am wrong. But as far as I know, **Results** for **Search Keywords** of the smart search, are stored and indexed in a special table of the db.
Smart Search at the moment only stores essential data, like **terms** and their **associative links**. This allows a quick and flexible search against them.

There is **No additional information** like the category for an article to return after a search, so apparently there is not a small piece of code  to copy/paste, to achieve what you want.

You would have to create additional complex queries for each of the results, among other development.